# How can I order Sunspot search results for a query on multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have two journal models, `ClientJournal` and `InstitutionJournal` and I'm using Sunspot to run a query which grabs records to display them together on the journals index page:

```
search = Sunspot.search ClientJournal, InstitutionJournal do
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 30
  order_by :created_at, :desc
end
```

This almost works but it splits the results into the two classes before ordering them, so `search.results` returns something like this:

```
created_at  class
09:30       ClientJournal
09:12       ClientJournal
08:57       ClientJournal
07:32       ClientJournal
09:45       InstitutionJournal
09:22       InstitutionJournal
09:07       InstitutionJournal
```

When what I actually want is this:

```
created_at  class
09:45       InstitutionJournal
09:30       ClientJournal
09:22       InstitutionJournal
09:12       ClientJournal
09:07       InstitutionJournal
08:57       ClientJournal
07:32       ClientJournal
```

Is there any way of telling Sunspot to order the results together as if they were the same model?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to search multiple models and first get individual model array and then sort them as i do:-

```
search = Sunspot.search ClientJournal,InstitutionJournal  do
           keywords(params[:search])
          #fulltext params[:search]
          order_by(:created_at, :desc)
          paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
         end 
##group them by class
 @results = search.results.group_by(&:class)
##get all clientjournals in created_at order
@clientjournals= @results[ClientJournal]
##OR do anything that you want with the array of cilentjournals
@clientjournals= @clientjournals.sort_by { |a| a.created_at }
```

Comment: The problem with that is you're only sorting the 10 results you get back for one page. If you remove the `paginate` from the search block to avoid that then you could end up with thousands of results in an array which will be really slow to sort.